# keep highest value of duplicate keys in dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, duplicates

For school i am writing a small program for a rankinglist for a game.
I am using dicts for this, with the name of the player as keyname, and the score as keyvalue.
there will be 10 games, and each game will have an automatic ranking system which i print to file.
ive already managed to code the ranking system, but now im facing a bigger challange which i cannot solve:

I have to make an overall ranking, which means someplayername can be in several contests with several scores, but i need to only keep the highest score of a duplicate.

**In short**: I need some help with keeping the duplicate key with the highest value:

like this:

```
dict1 = {"a": 6, "b": 4, "c": 2, "g": 1}
dict2 = {"a": 3, "f": 4, "g": 5, "d": 2}
dictcombined = {'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'g': 5, 'f': 4, 'd': 2}
```

the normal merge option just takes the second dict and thus that value.

thnx in advance

Comment: So you'll have dicts storing the score of each player. And there will be a list of 10 dicts for each game? You can write a function to take this list of dicts and merge/add them into one dict

Comment: Actually you could have a dict `total_scores`. The func would add each dict to this total

Comment: its my intetion to create a new dict of all the other dicts. to save myself for some extra trouble i just make the number of contests fixed (10 contests).
but when i compare for example dict1 and dict2, and some players participated in both, but with different scores, how to put the higehst score in the new dict?

Comment: Why use a dict instead of a list? What will the keys be?

Comment: How about describe the objective of your assignment more clearly. What is being ranked, how?

Comment: the name of the player is the keyname. the assigment is to write a program that makes an auto ranking system of the scores of each contest, and 1 auto ranking system of all the contests (aka overall ranking). the player with the highest score gets rank1, etc etc. so the ranking part is done with the value part of the dicts (the score), and this already works. but it works for every contest alone, not the overall rankinglist.
becuz 1 playername can only be once in every contest, but when i emrge all dicts together, 1playername can be in several contests with also different scores.

Comment: in the overall rankinglist duplcate playernames need to be reduced to only 1 (with highest score)

Comment: So you need to add up the scores for each player right? The player with the highest score is ranked highest?

Comment: thats correct. the program makes 1 dict after each contest, and writes this to file. when input is done, another def will get all files (json way) and make them dicts again. 
i had to do it the json way, becuz i had to keep in mind that the user could close the program, and then the dicts in memory would be gone).
after all dicts are readed again, they need to become 1 big dict and the duplicate key/pairs need to be fixed

Comment: Ok, so write a func that adds a dict to a total dict. It could iterate on each key inserting new keys if not already in the total otherwise adding to it if there

Comment: @mrjlp i was mistaken, i dont want to úp' the scores if a player has multplie score becuz he was in several contests. that player keeps only his highest score.

Comment: You need to begin your question with a clear description of what you're trying to do. It's still not clear

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do. Check out answer now

Comment: thank you for bearing with me. this is my first call for help, so im sry if i didnt discribe it well enough. with your solution below (the edited one) i can work, i think. i will try to use and implement it now

Comment: Great. Upvote and mark as resolved if it works out

Comment: it works like a charm, had to change 1 value ( >) but it does the job as i want. i upvoted your answer, but it seems ppl lower then 15 rep can only do invincible upvotes. thnx man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a function that will keep track of the highest scores for each player. It will add a player to the total if not already there, otherwise adding it if it's higher.
Something like this:

```
def addScores(scores, total):
    for player in scores:
        if player not in total or total[player] < scores[player]:
            total[player] = scores[player]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works like a charm:

```
dict1 = {"a": 6, "z": 4, "g": 1, "hh": 50, "ggg": 1}

dict2 = {"a": 3, "g": 5, "d": 2, "hh": 50}

for key in dict1:

    if key not in dict2 or dict1[key] > dict2[key]:
        dict2[key] = dict1[key]

print (dict1)
print (dict2)

dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}

print (dict3)
```

Now I can compare `dict3` with other dicts and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on [Matt Eding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8876606/matt-eding)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47086941/4518341) that compares each value individually instead of creating sets of values. As a plus, it doesn't need any imports.

```
def combine_dicts(chooser, *dicts):
    combined = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in combined:
                combined[k] = v
            else:
                combined[k] = chooser(v, combined[k])
    return combined
```

Usage:

```
>>> combine_dicts(max, dict1, dict2)
{'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'g': 5, 'f': 4, 'd': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my generalized solution to your question. It's a function that can combine an arbitrary number of dictionaries and has an option for other comparison functions should you want to say, keep track of the minimum values instead.

```
import collections

def combine_dicts(func, *dicts):
    default = collections.defaultdict(set)
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            default[k].add(v)
    return {k: func(v) for k, v in default.items()}
```

It uses a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with `set` as its *default_factory* to keep track of repetitions of keys with different values. Then it returns a dictionary comprehension to filter out the desired values.

```
dict1 = {"a": 6, "b": 4, "c": 2, "g": 1}
dict2 = {"a": 3, "d": 2, "f": 4, "g": 5}
dict_comb = combine_dicts(max, dict1, dict2)
print(dict_comb)  # -> {'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 4, 'g': 5}
```

Comment: Very nice! I posted [my own take on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61111483/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, surprisingly not proposed (since 100% built-in)

```
>>> dict(sorted([*dict1.items(), *dict2.items()]))
{'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 4, 'g': 5}
```

If your key-value pairs are less "lexicographic", you may want to target the numerics specifically, doing

```
>>> dict(sorted([*dict1.items(), *dict2.items()], key=lambda item: item[1]))
{'g': 5, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'f': 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/overview.html) for this. It also has a ton of other helpful functionality for working with data.

There's probably an ideal way to solve this, but the first thing I thought of is to create two Series (which are sort of like dicts), concatenate them, group by the labels (a, b, c, etc.), then get the max for each group.

```
import pandas as pd

s1, s2 = [pd.Series(d, name='Scores') for d in [dict1, dict2]]
result = pd.concat([s1, s2]).groupby(level=0).max()
```

```
>>> result
a    6
b    4
c    2
d    2
f    4
g    5
Name: Scores, dtype: int64
```

If you want the result as a dict:

```
>>> result.to_dict()
{'a': 6, 'b': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 2, 'f': 4, 'g': 5}
```