# Compare two dict values keeping lowest value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that takes in two dicts and returns a merged dict which containing all keys from both dicts and, if any keys exist in both dicts, comparing `prices` to keep the lowest value.

```
x = "{'45': 450, '43': 500, '44.5': 420, '39': 415, '47': 320, '46': 520, '44': 400, '47.5': 480, '40.5': 407, '42.5': 407, '42': 401, '38': 401, '45.5': 435, '37.5': 415, '41': 506, '38.5': 787, '36': 399, '36.5': 410, '48.5': 380, '40': 406, '48': 287, '49.5': 567, '50.5': 850, '51.5': 399, '49': 386}"
y = "{'36': 345.0, '36.5': 360.0, '37.5': 355.0, '38': 375.0, '38.5': 375.0, '39': 370.0, '40': 380.0, '40.5': 395.0, '41': 345.0, '42': 300.0, '42.5': 230.0, '43': 220.0, '44': 220.0, '44.5': 220.0, '45': 220.0, '45.5': 290.0, '46': 225.0, '47': 300.0, '47.5': 265.0, '48': 425.0, '48.5': 275.0, '49': 2000.0, '49.5': 1350.0, '51.5': 2000.0}"
```

I wrote this function to do it, but I believe it can be written in a more pythonic way

```
import ast
def compare_prices(dict1,dict2):
    temp1 = ast.literal_eval(dict1)
    temp2 = ast.literal_eval(dict2)
    for k,v in temp1.items():
        if k in temp2.keys():
            price = temp2[k] if temp2[k] else False
            if price:
                if v> price:
                    temp1[k] = price
                else:
                    temp1[k] = v
            else:
                temp1[k] = v
        else:
            temp1[k] = v
    for k,v in temp2.items():
        if k not in temp1.keys():
            try:
                temp1[k] = v if v else ''
            except TypeError:
                temp1[k] = v
    return dict(sorted(temp1.items()))
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [keep highest value of duplicate keys in dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082410/keep-highest-value-of-duplicate-keys-in-dicts)

Comment: @DirtyBit,  guess the expected output is mentioned in the title.

Comment: @dvlper an explicit output sample based on the given sample data is better than guessing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will meet your requirements. It's much simpler as it uses sets of keys so that `set1.intersection(set2)` contains all of the keys in both sets, so it can use this to make the comparisons, and `set2-set1` just contains those unique to `set2`, so they can simply be moved to `set1`

```
def compare_prices(dict1,dict2):
    temp1 = ast.literal_eval(dict1)
    temp2 = ast.literal_eval(dict2)
    set1 = set(temp1.keys())
    set2 = set(temp2.keys())
    for k in set1.intersection(set2):
        if temp1[k] > temp2[k]:
            temp1[k] = temp2[k]
    for k in set2 - set1:
        temp1[k] = temp2[k]
    return dict(sorted(temp1.items()))
```

Output is:

```
print(compare_prices(x, y))
{'36': 345.0, '36.5': 360.0, '37.5': 355.0, '38': 375.0, '38.5': 375.0, '39': 370.0, '40': 380.0, '40.5': 395.0, '41': 345.0, '42': 300.0, '42.5': 230.0, '43': 220.0, '44': 220.0, '44.5': 220.0, '45': 220.0, '45.5': 290.0, '46': 225.0, '47': 300.0, '47.5': 265.0, '48': 287, '48.5': 275.0, '49': 386, '49.5': 567, '50.5': 850, '51.5': 399}
```

Comment: this keeps all keys from both dicts right?  can you give more explanation on the logic please

Comment: Yes. It's modifying temp1, so any keys that exist only in temp1 will remain untouched, any that have a lower value in temp2 will be modified, and any that only exist in temp2 will be copied to temp1, so temp1 ends up with the complete list of keys with the lowest values.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a dictionary comprehension by merging the two dictionary with the minimum value of common keys:

```
{ **x, **y, **{k:min(x[k],y[k]) for k in x if k in y} }
```

output:

```
{'45': 220.0, '43': 220.0, '44.5': 220.0, '39': 370.0, '47': 300.0, '46': 225.0, '44': 220.0, '47.5': 265.0, '40.5': 395.0, '42.5': 230.0, '42': 300.0, '38': 375.0, '45.5': 290.0, '37.5': 355.0, '41': 345.0, '38.5': 375.0, '36': 345.0, '36.5': 360.0, '48.5': 275.0, '40': 380.0, '48': 287, '49.5': 567, '50.5': 850, '51.5': 399, '49': 386}
```

or you could write it like this (to avoid a double merge when most keys are common):

```
{ **x, **{ k:v for k,v in y.items() if k not in x or x[k]<v} }
```

or, you could use a descending sort on the concatenation of (key,value) tuples but sorting the whole data just to get minimums between matching keys is going to be very inefficient:

```
dict(sorted((*x.items(),*y.items()),key=lambda i:-i[1]))
```

If you are not comfortable with dictionary comprehensions, you could use a simple for loop:

```
merged = x.copy()
for k,v in y.items(): merged[k] = min(v, merged.get(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`**kwargs`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3) to merge the Dictionaries because it expands the contents in a dictionary as a collection of key-value pairs. And we can do the comparison to the `keys` that have multiple `value`s in the resultant dictionary,

```
import ast    

def compare_prices(dict1, dict2):
    temp1 = ast.literal_eval(dict1)
    temp2 = ast.literal_eval(dict2)
    tempDict = {**temp1, **temp2}   # two or more Dicts merged using **kwargs
    for key, value in tempDict.items():
        if key in temp1 and key in temp2:
            tempDict[key] = min([value, temp1[key]])    # sets the minimum value

    return tempDict
```

**Output**,

```
print(compare_prices(x, y))
#{'45': 220.0, '43': 220.0, '44.5': 220.0, '39': 370.0, '47': 300.0, '46': 225.0, '44': 220.0, '47.5': 265.0, '40.5': 395.0, '42.5': 230.0, '42': 300.0, '38': 375.0, '45.5': 290.0, '37.5': 355.0, '41': 345.0, '38.5': 375.0, '36': 345.0, '36.5': 360.0, '48.5': 275.0, '40': 380.0, '48': 287, '49.5': 567, '50.5': 850, '51.5': 399, '49': 386}
```

If you want a sorted dictionary you can use [`OrderedDict` from `collections`library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes)

```
import ast
from collections import OrderedDict

def compare_prices(dict1, dict2):
    temp1 = ast.literal_eval(dict1)
    temp2 = ast.literal_eval(dict2)
    tempDict = {**temp1, **temp2}   # two or more Dicts merged using **kwargs
    for key, value in tempDict.items():
        if key in temp1 and key in temp2:
            tempDict[key] = min([value, temp1[key]])    # sets the minimum value

    return OrderedDict(sorted(tempDict.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

**Output**,

```
print(compare_prices(x, y))
#OrderedDict([('36', 345.0), ('36.5', 360.0), ('37.5', 355.0), ('38', 375.0), ('38.5', 375.0), ('39', 370.0), ('40', 380.0), ('40.5', 395.0), ('41', 345.0), ('42', 300.0), ('42.5', 230.0), ('43', 220.0), ('44', 220.0), ('44.5', 220.0), ('45', 220.0), ('45.5', 290.0), ('46', 225.0), ('47', 300.0), ('47.5', 265.0), ('48', 287), ('48.5', 275.0), ('49', 386), ('49.5', 567), ('50.5', 850), ('51.5', 399)])
```